# What is this white, winged insect?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

I saw this insect crawling on a wall in the UK (Birmingham) today (March 28th). It's about 5mm long. I assumed it was a white fly, but having looked at other images of white files on google, I don't think it is! I assume the fact it has jet black eyes means it's normally nocturnal?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

At first I was thinking [**Trichoptera**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caddisfly), but the antenna were not long enough and I noticed your size is quite small (~5mm).

The small size and body stance made me think of the order [Neuroptera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroptera) (the net-winged insects).

Specifically, this specimen reminds me of the family [**Coniopterygidae**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coniopterygidae) (or the **dustywings**).

> A distinguishing feature is that like many other Neuroptera, dustywings carry their wings nearly side-by-side when at rest, whereas whiteflies carry them almost flat across the back  [the last part being related to the OP's original thought that their specimen was a [whitefly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitefly)]

Interestingly, unlike many other net-winged insects, the dustywings do not actually have "net-winged" venation -- just like the OP's specimen.

If this is in fact a dustywing, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coniopterygidae):

> These tiny insects can usually be determined to genus with a hand lens according to their wing venation, but to distinguish species, examination of the genitals by microscope is usually necessary.

Just as a reference, according to [here](http://lacewing.tamu.edu/Metakey/TerminalTaxonResults?scicriteria=contains&sciname=Conwentzia+pineticola&snscriteria=current) and [here](https://www.naturespot.org.uk/species/conwentzia-pineticola), a similar looking species called *Conwentzia pineticola* lives in the UK. You can see a picture of this species below:

[image]

<sup>Source: [NatureSpot](https://www.naturespot.org.uk/species/conwentzia-pineticola)</sup>

**Comments on appearance and characteristics:**

From Catherine A. Tauber et al. (2009) in [Encyclopedia of Insects (Second Edition)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780123741448001909):

> The Coniopterygidae is generally a very homogeneous family characterized by very small adults (forewing length 2–5 mm) with bodies covered by white waxy (“dusty”) secretions.

The family name means "dusty wing" [[source](https://bioone.org/journals/Paleontological-Contributions/volume-2014/issue-10F/PC.1808.15986/A-New-Genus-of-Dustywings-Neuroptera--Coniopterygidae-in-Late/10.17161/PC.1808.15986.full)] due to the usually conspicuous whitish dust of waxy scales on the wings of these insects. I can't tell if this "dusty" nature is apparent in your picture or whether your picture is simply blurry.

Regarding the antenna, Tauber et al mention:

> Adults have chewing mouthparts, large compound eyes located laterally on the head, and **multiarticulate antennae that are usually filiform (thread-like) or moniliform (with bead-like segments)**.

You can see a similar looking (and similar sized) specimen from the U.S. [here](https://bugguide.net/node/view/908107/bgimage) and one from Spain [here](https://www.biodiversidadvirtual.org/insectarium/Coniopterygidae-img189270.html). Additional images on [bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/11949/bgpage) seem to suggest that your specimen is in the subfamily **Coniopteryginae**.